# What does this c# bitshifting method do?

Tags: c#, byte, bitwise-operators

This method is pretty much copied from a java program, but I have worries it doesn't work as intended in c#
if ID is a byte, what does this do?

```
public int getBit(int position)
    {
        return (ID >> (position - 1)) & 1;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting/141873#141873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract from the ID the bit at the position passed.
Position should be 1-8
Returns the bit value (0-1)

For example:

```
ID = 128;  // 10000000
getBit(8); // returns 1

ID = 127;  // 01111111
getBit(8); // returns 0
```

Comment: behavior is same in C# and Java

Answer (score 1):

Returns non-zero if the bit at (position-1) is 1, otherwise returns 0